# Tracked Opens No

Tags: civimail, error, php, tracked-links

Track opens stopped working recently. Clicking on tracked opens gnerates the following error message:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Database' not found in /home/xxxxxx/public_html/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 3462
```

The site is running:

- Drupal 7.53
- CiviCRM 4.4.20
- PHP 5.4.x
- MySQL 5.5.x

Any ideas or next steps for troubleshooting would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

this seems to point at a broader drupal problem. is there something you've changed recently on the server? eg. updating php?

does the rest of your drupal site work ok?

Comment: I pretty recenty recently switched to the CloudLinux cPanel product from a straight WHM cPanel Centos 6 server. I'm going to turn off CloudLinux and revert to what I had before. Although I think the switch to ClooudLinux predated this track opens problem.
 
Drupal is running fine.

Comment: I just discovered that on a different CiviCRM site on the same server, that one is running 4.6.24 there is also an error message when click on track opens. The error is slightly different: Fatal error: Class 'SelectQuery' not found in /home/xxxxxx/public_html/includes/database/database.inc on line 827.

Comment: Both are errors with the drupal code. are you using fastcgi? you might have a different configuration for the "normal" drupal path and this one. What's the url of the page that has the error?

Comment: example.com/civicrm/mailing/report/event?reset=1&event=optout&mid=1144
example.com/civicrm/mailing/report/event?reset=1&event=opened&mid=1129
There are more, all seem to be CiviMail related.

Comment: server uses suPHP handler in PHP, not fastcgi.

Comment: Oh my, suPHP is still a thing? It's just aweful, move to a sane provider or update your tech stack.

Comment: I shared your comment with my host about suPHP. He wrote, "Until now it has been actively pushed over by cPanel  in latest versions.  Once they complete experimental to  stable on mod_ruid2 we will move away from suPHP." Maybe you have similar feelings about cPanel. In the meantime, I'm looking for the next troubleshooting step to sort this out. Thanks.

Comment: don't have any opinion on cpanel ;)